# How to always land a square box in 90 degree

Tags: unity, c#, unityscript

How can i Always Land a box in 90 degree

[image: Here What i have]

Here What i want
[image: Here What I want]

Here what i don't want
[image: here What i don't want]

```
{
public Rigidbody2D boxRb;
public float jumpSpeed;
 public Vector3 rotation;
public float rotationSpeed;
public bool rotationEnabled;
public float gravityMultiplier;
void FixedUpdate()
{
    if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
    {
        boxRb.velocity = jumpSpeed * Vector2.up;  
    }
    if (rotationEnabled = true)
    {
        transform.Rotate(rotation * rotationSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
    }
    if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(1))
    {
        boxRb.velocity += Vector2.up * Physics2D.gravity.y * (gravityMultiplier - 1) * Time.deltaTime;
    }




}
void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D collision)
{
    rotationEnabled = false;
    Debug.Log("Collided");
    rotationSpeed = 0f;
    boxRb.constraints = RigidbodyConstraints2D.FreezePositionX;
    transform.Rotate(0, 0, 90f);

}
void OnCollisionStay2D(Collision2D collision)
{
    rotationEnabled = false;
    Debug.Log("In collison");
    rotationSpeed = 0f;
    boxRb.constraints = RigidbodyConstraints2D.FreezePositionX;
}
void OnCollisionExit2D(Collision2D collision)
{
    rotationEnabled = true;
    Debug.Log("Free");
    rotationSpeed = 10f;
}
```

}

Comment: I think you need to include some more info... like what code do you have at the moment, what have you done so far, etc. It's hard for people to just guess these things and try to form a good answer from there.

Comment: @D.Kallan ok i added my code now check out

Answer (score 2):

### If you have a fixed speed:

If you know the starting speed (the speed you launch the box at) and the gravity, then the time the square spends in the air is `v / g`, where `v` is the speed and `g` is the gravitation. The square has to rotate At least `n * 90°` in this time frame, where `n` is an integer. This means, that the angular velocity must be `n * 90 / time`, where `n` is an integer and `time` is the time the square spends in the air.

### If you have a fixed angular velocity:

Similarily, he square must rotate at least `n * 90°`, where `n` is an integer. Pick a random `n` and divide `n * 90°` by the angular velocity to get the time the square needs to spend in the air. The velocity must be `g * time`, where `g` is the gravitational acceleration.

Comment: is there any way that box automatically fix its rotation after colliding using oncollisonenter2d

Comment: @Shantnu you could simply just set it's rotation back to zero in the OnCollisionEnter method.